# SQL авто index и мой index

Tags: sql, index

Инициализирую структуру БД через файл schema.sql(hibernate).
При создании foreign key база сама создаёт index для соответствующего поля(с именем по своему шаблону).
После этого добавляются мои индексы для тех же полей(с моими названиями).
Как отключить автосоздание индексов или удалять индекс для поля, для которого я хочу создать свой?
Перед каждым созданием индекса проверять его наличие по индексируемому полю?

И зависит ли это от базы данных?

Comment: foreign key - уникальный?

Comment: Название? Да.)
Я решил сделать так: связь REFERENCES создаётся после создания индекса.